# PHP strtotime problems with minutes

Tags: php, time

Is that normal that this line:

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:m:s a", strtotime('2012-03-18 12:55:00'))
```

gives me 2012-03-18 12:03:00 pm

Whatever the minutes I enter, I always get 03 minutes... weird.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your date string format should be :

`Y-m-d h:i:s a`

[PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has this to say about formatting a local time/date -

- `i` - Minutes with leading zeros
- `m` - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros

What you were seeing as `03` was actually the month - March :)

Comment: Haha! Thanks. Programming on week ends, that what's happen :)

Comment: LOL - yep... Occupational hazards ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `m` in the date function represents months, not minutes. For minutes, you want to use `i`:

```
Y-m-d h:i:s a
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP's `date` function, the code for minutes is `i` not `m`:

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", strtotime('2012-03-18 12:55:00'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "minutes" are actually "months". Use `i` as your date code:

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", strtotime('2012-03-18 12:55:00'))
```