# Need help pulling correct DATETIME

Tags: php

I have a column in my datebase that stores a DATETIME. For some reason when I pull it back and run it through `date();` it will not display the correct time format.

The DATETIME I'm storing is: `2014-03-07 12:00:57`

**The method I'm using to display it:**

```
date("y-m-d m:h",strtotime($row["date"]));
```

The time that I'm getting when I pull it back: `14-03-13 03:12`

I am using `date_default_timezone_get();` to display the correct timezone.
Why is this happening?

Comment: It's been asked a thousand times before. But still: `m` stands for **month**, *not* minute. Use `i` instead. See http://php.net/date

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP strtotime problems with minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759720/php-strtotime-problems-with-minutes)

Comment: @AmalMurali Your answer is a possible duplicate of the one below.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, @Christian. That's not *my* answer. The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`m` is month. `h` is hours. `i` is minutes.

```
date("y-m-d h:i",strtotime($row["date"]));
```

Comment: wow. there you have it. Thanks man! I did use m, but I've been up all night coding so maybe a bit dyslexic today?

Comment: It always helps to read the documentation for the relevant function, @Christian :)

Answer (score 0):

check hour, minute and second (is missing)

```
 date("y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($row["date"]));
```